# Need colorful synonym for "dumbfounded" or "baffled"

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a colorful synonym for "dumbfounded" or "baffled".  It's on the tip of my tongue.  It's a multi-syllable word.

---

Context: "I checked with xxx and yyy (experts).  They were both as *dumbfounded* as I was by So-and-So's letter, saying they've never heard of a request for *m* being treated as *n*.

(An administrator had confused two completely different rights and their legal underpinnings.)

---

*Hornswaggled* is the closest so far.  (The dictionary I consulted said *hornswoggled*, and it gave a very different definition.)  But I think there's something that's just one notch more mainstream than that, only that I can't remember it.

---

I'm seeing some suggestions that don't mean the same thing as *dumbfounded/baffled*.  Here's the definition for *dumbfounded*: "to make speechless with amazement; astonish."

Here's a made-up similar context:

> I double-checked with my botany professor.  She was as ____________ as I was by your lecture notes, saying she's never seen a maple confused with an oak before.

**EDIT:**  Guys, "hornswaggled/hornswoggled" is *colorful*.  *Astonished* (for example) is *not* colorful.

Comment: There's always "hornswaggled".

Comment: Please include context where the "colorful" synonym would be used. Otherwise, your question might be closed.

Comment: I'll give you my million-dollar opinion if you can just give me a feel for audience...are you writing it up for work? My hunch is yes, so I'll plead that 'hornswaggled' gets the axe. Although it's impossible to say it w/out smiling. :) *You're wise to be picky on this one, since many of the word choices are almost cartoonish...too boisterous if we're describing an adult who's contemplating something..if all the action is silently happening inside her head.

Comment: I don't think *hornswaggled* fits.  *Hornswaggled* is what you are when you are tricked or deceived usually into buying something you wouldn't have bought had you known what was happening.   *Dumfounded* means extremely surprised to the point of speechlessnes (my definition) and although you might be mad to the point of speechlessness when you figure out you've been hornswaggled, it's not quite the same thing.

Comment: Have you tried consulting a [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/dumbfounded?s=t)?

Comment: @AndyT - - yes.

Comment: "Bamboozled", perhaps?

Comment: @Jim - I did a little research on "hornswoggled" (apparently the correct spelling) after I placed the above comment.  It did originally mean "tricked" or "deceived", as you say.  However, many of my generation know it because "I'll be hornswoggled" was a common minced oath on TV westerns of the late 50s (thanks to the censorship of the era).  In particular I'm thinking that the Andy Devine character in *The Adventures of Wild Bill Hickok* used it regularly.  (If not him then a similar character in a similar show.)  And the movie *Calamity Jane* uses the word in this sense in 1953.

Comment: We could add *stunned* to already proposed answers, but "appaled" seems to better match the examples.

Comment: There is *comboggled* also.

Comment: dumbfounded seems colourful enough!

Comment: @curiousdannii - I couldn't wait any longer to send my letter, and I did actually use dumbfounded.  Nothing else that had been proposed fit as well.  But I keep feeling there's some slightly funny-sounding word for this that I heard somewhere.  Some kind of regionalism, where you could figure out what's meant from the context.

Comment: 'hornswaggled' means cheated or deceived. "I was hornswaggled out of $50 dollars"

Comment: F***ed if I know a colourful word for baffled

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Astonished, astounded, flabbergasted, flummoxed, gobsmacked, speechless, stupefied.

Comment: I guess I'll accept *gobsmacked*.  It feels like the same thing to me as dumbfounded, and it's more colorful.  (Unfortunately, it was too strong and too colorful for me to use in my letter.)  And Tahlia was the first to suggest it.

Comment: @aparente001 which begs the question why did you set up a bounty in the first place?  Tahlia's list was posted,  precisely,  four minutes after you submitted your question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I have been disappointed in the answers that were posted after I set up the bounty.  Do you really see a post-bounty question that is better?  I couldn't award the bounty to *dumbfounded*.

Comment: You could have always just used a thesaurus instead of asking this site. If you were unhappy with the answers, you did not have to award anyone at all.

Comment: I always find "Speechless" to be amusing when someone says it of themselves. But then, I am perfect.

Answer (score 6):

Consider,

[***discombobulated***](http://www.kaplaninternational.com/blog/definition-discombobulated/)

> to discombobulate: to confuse; befuddle [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/discombobulate)

***obfusticated***

> : *Dial.* obfuscated; confused; bewildered [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obfusticated)

[***confusticated***](http://everything2.com/title/Confusticate)

> confusticate: *Sl.* to confuse or perplex; bewilder [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/confusticate)

***metagrabolized/metagrobolized***

> : totally perplexed and mixed up [WordNet by Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/metagrobolized)

***addlepated***

> : being mixed up : confused [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/addlepated)

Comment: "discombobulated" does seem to be a popular word on ELU, I think it's the only place I've ever heard it. I do love "confusticated" though :)

Comment: Discombobulated was going to be my answer. It not only fits the definition for the OP's request, its just a funny word to say outloud.

Answer (score 2):

**bamboozled**

> I double-checked with my botany professor. She was as [bamboozled](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bamboozled) as I was by your lecture notes, saying she's never seen a maple confused with an oak before.

- 2. to perplex; mystify; confound.
     Synonyms: befog, bewilder, puzzle, **baffle**, **dumbfound**.

Dictionary.com explains further

> **Bamboozle** is one of those words that has been confounding etymologists for centuries. [...] By 1712, it had acquired the sense “to perplex; mystify.” It is not known for certain, but this sense might have emerged under the influence of the Scottish word *bumbaze* (or bombaze), meaning “to confuse,” similar in both sound and meaning. Given the befuddling qualities of alcohol, it's not too surprising to find that, in the 1800's, *bamboozle* showed up on college campuses as a slang term for “drunk.”

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variety of colorful words I found using [**Thesaurus.com**](http://www.thesaurus.com/):

> **thunderstruck**
>   [thuhn-der-struhk]
>
> **adjective**
>
> 1. overcome with consternation; confounded; astounded:
>
>    *He was thunderstruck by the news of his promotion*
> 2. Archaic. struck by a thunderbolt.

**[Thunderstruck](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/thunderstruck?s=t)**

> **buffaloed, buffaloing**
>
> **verb** (used with object) *Informal*
>
> 5. to puzzle or baffle; confuse; mystify:
>
>    *He was buffaloed by the problem*.
> 6. to impress or intimidate by a display of power, importance, etc.
>
>    *The older boys buffaloed him.*

[**Buffaloed**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/buffaloed?s=t)

> **bemuse**[bih-myooz]
>
> **verb** (used with object)
>
> 1. to bewilder or confuse (someone).

[**Bemuse**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bemuse?s=t)

> **flabbergast** [flab-er-gast]
>
> **verb** (used with object)
>
> 1. to overcome with surprise and bewilderment; astound

**[Flabbergast](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/flabbergast?s=t)**

> **disconcert** [dis-kuh n-surt]
>
> **verb** (used with object)
>
> 1. to disturb the self-possession of; perturb; ruffle
>
>    *Her angry reply disconcerted me completely.*
> 2. to throw into disorder or confusion; disarrange
>
>    *He changed his mind and disconcerted everybody's plans*

**[Disconcert](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disconcert?s=t)**

> **stupefy** [stoo-puh-fahy, styoo-]
>
> **verb** (used with object), **stupefied**, **stupefying**.
>
> 1. to put into a state of little or no sensibility; benumb the faculties of; put into a stupor.
> 2. to stun, as with a narcotic, a shock, or a strong emotion.
> 3. to overwhelm with amazement; astound; astonish.

**[Stupefy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stupefy?s=t)**

> **boggle** [bog-uh l]
>
> **verb** (used with object), **boggled, boggling.**
>
> 1. to overwhelm or bewilder, as with the magnitude, complexity, or abnormality of
>
>    *The speed of light boggles the mind.*
> 2. to bungle; botch.
>
> **verb** (used without object), **boggled, boggling.**
>
> 3. to hesitate or waver because of scruples, fear, etc.
> 4. to start or jump with fear, alarm, or surprise; shrink; shy.
> 5. to bungle awkwardly.
> 6. to be overwhelmed or bewildered.

**[Boggled](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/boggle?s=t)**

I personally thought these were "filled with color"

Answer (score 1):

You may be ***befuzzled***.

> Confused, baffled, bemused, perplexed.
>   "I don't know, you've got me all befuzzled!"
>   <sub>[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=befuzzled)</sub>

Comment: I think the original word would be befuddled. For anyone who wants a the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the list of synonyms that Google suggests for *dumbfounded* :

> - astonished, astounded, amazed, staggered, surprised, startled, stunned, confounded, nonplussed, stupefied, dazed, dumbstruck, open-mouthed, agape, speechless, at a loss for words, thunderstruck, goggle-eyed, wide-eyed;
> - taken aback, thrown, shaken (up), unnerved, disconcerted, discomposed, bewildered;
> - (informal:) flabbergasted, floored, flummoxed, knocked for six, knocked sideways, knocked out, bowled over, blown away, unable to believe one's eyes/ears;
> - (informal:) gobsmacked

And some verbs:

- take someone's breath away, take by surprise, stop someone in their tracks, strike dumb, leave open-mouthed, leave aghast, catch off balance;
- (informal:) knock the stuffing out of, blow someone's mind

Doubtlessly I've repeated some of others' words, but I'm too lazy to check one by one. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility no-one appears to have mentioned: `stunned as a mullet`, or `like a stunned mullet`, though I think this is Australian vernacular. From the Macquarie dictionary (3ed), under **stunned**:

> *phrase* **2. like a stunned mullet**, *Colloquial* **a.** in complete bewilderment or astonishment. **b.** in a state of inertia: **Now you sit there like a stunned mullet.* - ʙᴀʀʀʏ ᴅɪᴄᴋᴇɴꜱ, 1985.

Comment: What does *mullet* mean in that context?  Surely, not the haircut,

Comment: It's a fish. They look pretty stunned when you catch them and knock them on the head (I was going to use bonk rather than knock but I don't want to cause even *more* confusion given certain definitions of rhe word "bonk").

Comment: Interestingly enough, Macquarie (3ed, so it may be outdated) doesn't list that hairstyle as one of the definitions of `mullet`.

Answer (score 0):

Nonplussed: surprised and confused. Particularly nice, since a lot of the folks who use this word are a bit nonplussed by the actual definition.

Goggling: staring with amazement and wonder.

I've heard "Agog" used in a similar context, but it's not proper usage.

Additionally both Gobsmacked and Befuddled might work.

Comment: Gobsmacked looks promising for my context.  I will put it into my draft and then let it ferment a bit before I decide.

Comment: Nonplussed means "less than enthused by" (or as the word itself implies, *nothing added by*) the subject in question. A synonym phrase for nonplussed might be "not impressed". It has nothing to do with the states of confusion or clarity.

Comment: Goggling and agog are both descriptive of facial expressions and states of wonder/amazement. If I accidentally walked into a room where Angelina Jolie was starkers I would certainly be agog and probably goggle her but I would in no way be confused about what I was seeing. 8-D

Comment: @O.M.Y. You should check your definition of "nonplussed" again. That's at best an informal definition due to erroneous usage by people who don't actually know what nonplussed means. That's why I referenced the actual, as opposed to supposed, definition in my answer. Also, check up on agog as well. People tend to associate it with goggling since they're phonetically similar, but agog is appropriately used to describe an anticipatory or expectant state.

Comment: Thanks for proving out my assessment of nonplussed though ;)

Comment: @Misneac: I stand corrected! I just looked at the [Oxford Dictionary definition for "nonplussed"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/nonplussed) and it confirms your definition (which I had never heard) but at the same time it points out that my definition has also become common usage in North America with the synonymous meaning of "unperturbed".

Comment: @O.M.Y. I know it's often used that way and it makes me sad since I'm a N. American myself. People from the US already get a bad rap from British English speakers so I try to avoid shooting myself in the foot where I can. It's one of the more misused words in the US, so perfectly it's understandable.

Comment: @Misneac - When it comes to *nonplussed*, British speakers are as bad as those in the US. When I found out what it actually meant I decided to never use it again - too much a likelihood of being misunderstood, whether used correctly or not.

Answer (score 0):

Bedevilled: Be confusing or perplexing to; cause to be unable to think clearly

*Example:* These questions bedevil even the experts

I think this perfectly suits your context. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's not too multi-syllabicated but how about:
'**Stumped**' or '**Flummoxed**' ? (as per The Collins dictionary)

- **stumped**
  at a loss, at one's wits' end, at sea, baffled, brought to a standstill, floored     (informal)   flummoxed, in despair, nonplussed, perplexed, stymied, uncertain which way to turn.
- **flummoxed**
  at a loss, at sea, baffled, bewildered, foxed, mystified, nonplussed, stumped, stymied.

Answer (score 0):

**Aporia**
noun - an irresolvable internal contradiction or logical disjunction in a text, argument, or theory.

Hard to use in place of dumbfounded though, and it might baffle some readers.

Comment: Was requesting an adjective.