# Phrase for showing your astonishment

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I am looking for an expression which shows that I'm surprised at something.
 For example:

> What *sorcery* is this?

What is a good *formal* expression to show that I'm completely astonished and also make it seem as if the object I'm surprised at is impossible?

Edit: formal

Comment: Your title question seems totally different from that in the body text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need colorful synonym for "dumbfounded" or "baffled"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286364/need-colorful-synonym-for-dumbfounded-or-baffled)

Comment: Or, for an exclamation, [Stereotypical recognisable educated version of 'Gosh!'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/469717/stereotypical-recognisable-educated-version-of-gosh/469719#469719).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I would say it's different as that question is asking for a specific multi-syllable word.

Comment: The answers include phrases: 'Here's the list of synonyms that Google suggests for dumbfounded:

astonished, astounded, amazed, staggered, surprised, startled, stunned, confounded, nonplussed, stupefied, dazed, dumbstruck, open-mouthed, agape, speechless, at a loss for words, thunderstruck, goggle-eyed, wide-eyed;
taken aback, thrown, shaken (up), unnerved, disconcerted, discomposed, bewildered;
(informal:) flabbergasted, floored, flummoxed, knocked for six, knocked sideways, knocked out, bowled over, blown away, unable to believe one's eyes/ears;
(informal:) gobsmacked'.

Comment: @Lordology - the OP is _looking for an expression_. There's no mention of multi-syllable word

Comment: @Lordology "This is amazing!" ... "Amazing!" / "Baffling!" show that many of the adjectives listed in the 'Need colorful synonym for "dumbfounded" or "baffled" ' thread overlap almost exactly. Participial clauses are also suggested there; "I'm blown away" is easily recoverable.  'Zounds' is of course given in the 'Gosh!' thread.

Comment: @Lordology But none of your examples explicitly does that either. 'expressing surprise or indignation'. 'Exclamation of surprise, dismay, or alarm' .... I'll stop adding additional bloatware myself now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I like the old-fashioned but great:

> "*Zounds!*"

Defined as

> *interj. archaic, humorous*
> **expressing surprise or indignation**
>
> > *‘‘Zounds,’ said the Admiral, ‘it goes on for ever.’’*

Not exactly informal, but not exclusively formal.

A contraction of "God's wounds" (those of Christ on the Cross), it can be pronounced *zuːndz* (zoo-nds) or *zaʊndz* (zow-nds).

[Lexico Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/zounds)

---

There's also

> *[goodness gracious](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/goodness-gracious)!*
>
> > Also, good gracious; gracious sakes. Exclamation of surprise, dismay, or alarm, as in Goodness gracious! You've forgotten your ticket. Both goodness and gracious originally alluded to the good (or grace) of God, but these colloquial expressions, which date from the 1700s, are not considered either vulgar or blasphemous.

---

> [*stone the crows!*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stone-the-crows?topic=expressions-of-surprise)
>
> > used as an expression of surprise:
> >
> > > *Well, stone the crows - it's five o'clock already!*

---

> [*Heavens above!/good heavens!*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/heavens-above) also [*God almighty!*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/god-christ-almighty?q=god%20almighty)
>
> > used to express surprise or anger
> > *God almighty* :an expression of anger or surprise. Some people consider this offensive.

There are in fact many *heavens/lord/god* combinations, and all of these can be used alone.

---

> [*wonders never cease!*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wonders-never-cease?topic=expressions-of-surprise)
>
> > *humorous.* an expression of surprise used when something unusual or unexpected happens

---

**Bonus answer:**

> [*ventre-saint-gris!* or *ventrebleu!*](https://en.bab.la/dictionary/french-english/ventre-saint-gris)
>
> > French: *literally:* "Sacred grey belly" *translation*: *[Begad!](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/begad?s=t)*
> >
> > > *Probably* *"by god"*:  an emphatic exclamation

Comment: Thanks, anything a bit more formal?

Comment: @NoLand'sMan I'll add to my answer

Comment: @NoLand'sMan Done.

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain why they did what they did so I can build over constructive criticism.

Comment: As you are probably aware, I'm totally against the treatment of ELU as primarily a Q & A service that is all things to all people; its mission statement is that it be / become an easily searchable (for numerous visitors) repository of sound English usages and the rationale behind those usages. Having multiple threads giving what are essentially lists of synonyms (the term covers words, phrases etc), doubtless for sightly differently phrased questions with often trivial restrictions (answer must be multi-syllabled / begin with a 'j'),  is unscholarly and ultimately unhelpful. If people ...

Comment: wish to contribute what they think is a better or otherwise useful answer, the original question is where it should go; bloatware is unacceptable. Often, people complaining about close-votes on the grounds of duplication never bother to do any tidying of the site themselves. / The upvoting of answers to questions already signalled reasonably as duplicates (within the spirit of the term) sends out a wrong message to other users.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth First of all, I don't need to explain your first link, as that is a list of adjectives.  In regard to your second link, the question has technically not been properly answered, so it's correct that I could've posted my answer there.  It is true that EL&U is not a Q&A service, but it also isn't a library.  Questions that have been exactly answered before are marked as duplicates, but this question cannot, as the duplicate "question" has not been answered to a sufficient standard.  If the site worked this way, it would just be a string of redirects to other empty answers.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This would work if ELU was perfect, but it's not.  Most new visitors coming to ask a question do not do research, so wasting time searching for duplicates is not the answer.  If there *is* a  question with an accepted answer, you mark as duplicate.  If the question has not received/has bad/little answers, there's no use redirecting to a dead end or answering the question at the dead end and redirecting the OP there.  Otherwise you may as well answer the visitor's question─there's no harm in that.